# C++ Casting a string to an unsigned long long

Tags: c++, string, casting, unsigned-long-long-int

In C++ two options I've found for casting a string to an unsigned long long are:

```
boost::lexical_cast<unsigned long long>(theString);  //option#1
stoull(theString);                                   //option#2
```

What are the differences?

Is one preferred?  If yes, why?

Are there other options that are better?  If yes, why is the option better?

Comment: If you don't want to have to include boost then using `stoull()` would be prefered

Comment: To somebody that is acquainted with C++ but not with boost, the first one might seem like a compile-time "operation" (not sure if that can be counted as a disadvantage though).

Comment: Note: both are string to number conversions (none is a cast, you might adjust the title)

Answer (score 4):

[`std::stoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) receives the vigorous review that the standard library gets.  **Prefer it.**

You would need to use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) if:

- You are using a C++ standard *before* C++11.
- You are converting to a templated type that *may* be `unsigned long long`, but *may* be another type.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize `std::stoull` was new for C++11.